# Why do I keep getting "column _id does not exist" error in Django?

Tags: django

I keep getting `column qanda_question.category_id does not exist` error. Let me show you my model.

```
class QuestionCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", primary_key = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.category))

class Question(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    category = models.ForeignKey(QuestionCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.category)+" "+str(self.number)+". "+str(self.title))
```

I've tried deleting all the migrations files in `migrations` folder except `init.py`, but the error persists. What do you think is the problem? 
 +++ FYI, The directory where the `models.py` is located is `qanda`.
 +++ Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column qanda_question.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...a_question"."title", "qanda_question"."question", "qanda_que...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1796, in changelist_view
    'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1152, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/ubuntu/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/qanda/question/
Exception Value: column qanda_question.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...a_question"."title", "qanda_question"."question", "qanda_que...
```

Comment: Can you add the *complete error traceback*?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Sure. I've edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the migrations? and what is the result of ***`python manage.py showmigrations`***?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes. I've run both ```makemigrations``` and ```migrate```. What I get as the result of ```showmigrations``` is ```0001_initial```, since I deleted all the other migrations and retried. :(

Comment: if you deleted all migrations, you have to delete the db too. After deleting the DB, again migrate

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Oh how do I delete the entire DB?

Comment: That action is specific to the database you are using. check to correspond doc

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Okay but is it okay to just delete all the relation I have in my app and migrate all over?